# How to call `ERL_NIF_TERM` when I know that it is a funciton?

Tags: erlang, erlang-nif

My goal is to write a `NIF` that calls arbitrary Erlang function like `fun(N) -> N + 1 end.` or `{M, F, A}`, or any other valid way to do it. I need to operaite on a result out of the Erlang function.

As far as I see, [the docs](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_is_fun) don't say much about how to call `ERL_NIF_TERM` when I know for sure it is a function. As such I am stumbled upon the following code:

```
const ERL_NIF_TERM fun = ...; // does not matter how do I get it

if (!enif_is_fun(env, fun))
  goto BADARG; // report an error

// hm... how do I call the `fun`?
```

After a brief investigation, I discovered the `typedef struct { ... } ErlNifFunc`, but I still - have no idea how to get it out from the `ERL_NIF_TERM` safely.